# How to change multiple subscription products strings in woocommerce subscriptions?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, str-replace, woocommerce-subscriptions

I have multiple subscription products in my website with monthly, yearly and weekly.

I am running this code which is working fine (changing "month to 30 days ") but only works for the products with "Monthly" how can I apply it to change the the string for weekly and yearly also?

Thank you

```
function wc_subscriptions_custom_price_string( $pricestring ) {
    $newprice = str_replace( 'month', '30 days', $pricestring );
    return $newprice;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string', 'wc_subscriptions_custom_price_string' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscription_price_string', 'wc_subscriptions_custom_price_string' );
```

Comment: Hi @Imran! What is your attempt on solving the problem? Can you post what you have tried so far? Do you know what string you want to replace with what? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do similar replaces, you can even embed them, like:

```
function wc_subscriptions_custom_price_string( $pricestring ) {
    $newprice = str_replace(
        'month', 
        '30 days', 
        str_replace(
            'year',
            '365 days',
            str_replace(
                'week',
                '7 days',
                $pricestring
            )
        ) 
    );
    return $newprice;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string', 'wc_subscriptions_custom_price_string' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscription_price_string', 'wc_subscriptions_custom_price_string' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to replace all strings you need **given that you know, what it says *right now***.

I can't find the documentation, but given that the `$pricestring` takes on values `biweekly`, `weekly`, `yearly`, I would follow the pattern, and try:

```
function wc_subscriptions_custom_price_string( $pricestring ) {
    $newprice = str_replace( 'biweekly', '14 days', $pricestring );
    $newprice = str_replace( 'weekly', '7 days', $pricestring );
    $newprice = str_replace( 'yearly', '365 days', $pricestring );
    return $newprice;
}
```

Basically, it takes the `$pricestring` and replaces whatever the text (the first parameter) found inside, and replaces it with whatever text (the second parameter), saving it again and returning the modified `$newprice`.

Notice the order of `biweekly` and `weekly` if you want to avoid accidentally rewriting `weekly` in `biweekly`.

Comment: Thanks for your coment @Kit O, I did the same previously but it's working only for 1 parameter not all three.

Comment: Not sure, what do you mean by that. I think you essencially need to know, what is the current value, to be able to replace it. Maybe you can have a read on https://laurena.blog/collecting-donations-with-woocommerce/ then, and see if there is something helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Looking at the article and the documentation: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/customers-extend-subscription-expiration-date/ it looks replacing the last word should work. Have you tried typing in `"week"` and `"year"`, @ImranIrshad?